# How to handle BACnet/SC Certificate expiry in BACnet devices

Tags: bacnet, bacnet4j

I need help with implementing an alarm/event to notify when a certificate in BACnet secure connect links is going to expire within the next 90 days.

Should I use event notifications or directly use the BACnet Multi-state/analog Value point Object to generate the alarm? Which approach is preferable?

Answer (score 0):

For monitoring certificate expiration in BACnet Secure Connect Links, if you only need to track the next 90 days, using a BACnet Multi-state/Analog Value Point object could be simpler. If you want more flexibility for different alarms, then go for event notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Since the cert expiring could trip-up your connectivity, I'd be tempted to say it would be nice if you could have (/at least consider having) both; the event notifications sounding like the right but possibly more complex way to do things, but a Multi-State Input could appease developers or logic integrating with your system.

But on the whole, maybe you should be managing the certificates at a higher-level, in a possibly better (cross-cutting all devices) agnostic way.